# SQL syntax error?

Tags: sql, syntax, phpmyadmin, mysql

Does anyone know what is wrong with the following SQL query?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrWorlds (                     # World table
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 worldname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE                    # Name of world
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrEntries (                    # User/Group table
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,                               # Name of user/group
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                # ID of the world the     user/group belongs to
 type TINYINT NOT NULL,                                   # Type denotes the entry type.     0 for a user, 1 for a group
 CONSTRAINT NameWorld UNIQUE (name, worldid, type),
 ENTRYINDEX
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrPermissions (                             # Table of     permission nodes
 permid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 permstring VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                                      # Permission node
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                             # Entry whom this     node belongs to
 CONSTRAINT PrEntryPerm UNIQUE (entryid, permstring),
 FOREIGN KEY(entryid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrInheritance (                  # Table of parent-child     relationships
 uinheritid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 childid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                  # Child entry
 parentid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                 # Parent entry
 parentorder INTEGER NOT NULL,                              # Denotes order of     inheritance. 
                                                            # Groups override other     groups' permissions/data 
                                                            # below them in the results
 CONSTRAINT PrParent UNIQUE (childid, parentid),
 CONSTRAINT PrOrderedInheritance UNIQUE (childid, parentorder),
 CONSTRAINT PrNoSelfInherit CHECK (childid <> parentid),
 FOREIGN KEY(childid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(parentid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrWorldBase (      # Table of the default groups in that world
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,
 defaultid INTEGER,                           # Default group
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(defaultid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrData (
 dataid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL ,                  # ID entry whom this data node belongs to
 path VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  # Path to data node (e.g. "prefix", "build")
 data VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  # Data node in string form (o.toString())
 CONSTRAINT PrDataUnique UNIQUE (entryid, path),
 FOREIGN KEY(entryid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrTracks (
 trackid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 trackname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                      # Track name
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                   # ID of world track belongs             to
     CONSTRAINT TracksUnique UNIQUE (trackid, worldid),
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrTrackGroups (
 trackgroupid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 trackid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                          # ID of track
 gid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                              # ID of group in     track
 groupOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,                                       # Denotes position of     the group in the track
 CONSTRAINT TrackGroupsUnique UNIQUE (trackid, gid),
 FOREIGN KEY(trackid) REFERENCES PrTracks(trackid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(gid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

It throws this error when run in the newest version of phpMyAdmin:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CA' at line 8
```

Running the newest available MySQL server via yum, PHP version is 5.3 with php-mysql added via yum as well.
All of this is running on CentOS 5.5 64bit.

Comment: The error is at `ENTRYINDEX`.

Comment: What is ENTRYINDEX on line 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `ENTRYINDEX` and change `AUTOINCREMENT` to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Correct code would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrWorlds (                     # World table
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 worldname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE                    # Name of world
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrEntries (                    # User/Group table
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,                               # Name of user/group
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                # ID of the world the     user/group belongs to
 type TINYINT NOT NULL,                                   # Type denotes the entry type.     0 for a user, 1 for a group
 CONSTRAINT NameWorld UNIQUE (name, worldid, type),
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrPermissions (                             # Table of     permission nodes
 permid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 permstring VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                                      # Permission node
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                             # Entry whom this     node belongs to
 CONSTRAINT PrEntryPerm UNIQUE (entryid, permstring),
 FOREIGN KEY(entryid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrInheritance (                  # Table of parent-child     relationships
 uinheritid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 childid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                  # Child entry
 parentid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                 # Parent entry
 parentorder INTEGER NOT NULL,                              # Denotes order of     inheritance. 
                                                            # Groups override other     groups' permissions/data 
                                                            # below them in the results
 CONSTRAINT PrParent UNIQUE (childid, parentid),
 CONSTRAINT PrOrderedInheritance UNIQUE (childid, parentorder),
 CONSTRAINT PrNoSelfInherit CHECK (childid <> parentid),
 FOREIGN KEY(childid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(parentid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrWorldBase (      # Table of the default groups in that world
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,
 defaultid INTEGER,                           # Default group
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(defaultid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrData (
 dataid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 entryid INTEGER NOT NULL ,                  # ID entry whom this data node belongs to
 path VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  # Path to data node (e.g. "prefix", "build")
 data VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  # Data node in string form (o.toString())
 CONSTRAINT PrDataUnique UNIQUE (entryid, path),
 FOREIGN KEY(entryid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrTracks (
 trackid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 trackname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                      # Track name
 worldid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                   # ID of world track belongs             to
     CONSTRAINT TracksUnique UNIQUE (trackid, worldid),
 FOREIGN KEY(worldid) REFERENCES PrWorlds(worldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrTrackGroups (
 trackgroupid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 trackid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                          # ID of track
 gid INTEGER NOT NULL,                                              # ID of group in     track
 groupOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,                                       # Denotes position of     the group in the track
 CONSTRAINT TrackGroupsUnique UNIQUE (trackid, gid),
 FOREIGN KEY(trackid) REFERENCES PrTracks(trackid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(gid) REFERENCES PrEntries(entryid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the default table type on your database is `MyISAM` or other? `FOREIGN KEY` is supported by `INNODB` but the SQL doesn't specify what table types to use.